# How to calculate what wind speed is required to lift 1kg?

Tags: motor

as the title says, i want to calculate how much km/h is required to lift 1kg of weight.
Please explain this to me as simple as you can since i'm really noob in this.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share more on your application? what are you doing? why?

Comment: If you use a balloon, it doesn't require any wind speed at all. Are you talking about some kind of kite? What is the significance of the [tag:motor] tag?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* n_n, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very difficult question and as far as I know it is nearly impossible to answer in that way. You need to define the "sail" you use further. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forces_on_sails#Forces_on_sails) and specify your problem further.

Perhaps this is enugh for you:

**Energy of moving air**

$E = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \rho \cdot A \cdot v_{wind}^3 \cdot t$

where:

- E - Energy
- $\rho$ - Density of air
- A - Area of the sail
- v - velocity of the wind
- t - time

**Energy of lifted weight**

$ E = m \cdot g \cdot h(t) = m \cdot g \cdot v_{lifitng} \cdot t $

where:

- m - mass of the object
- g - 9.81 m/s^2
- h(t) - height at time t

Assuming that you have a system which can convert the wind energy in a perfect way to potential energy, than you can at least calculate some boundary values. If you want your question answered, specify the geometry of the sail, wind angle etc. further.